Marketing Cloud iOS Push open count is always 0
We are on Markeitng cloud sdk 8.1.2 and SFMC 1.1.2
As per documenation have implemented when notification received:
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    SFMCSdk.mp.setNotificationRequest(response.notification.request)
    completionHandler()
}

I have enabled the analytics value in the code as per the documentation.
let mobilePushConfiguration = PushConfigBuilder(appId: appId)
        .setAccessToken(accessToken)
        .setApplicationControlsBadging(true)
        .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(URL(string: "https://mcpkyttp9ysj12c63hz4qs96dbyq.device.marketingcloudapis.com/")!)
        .setMid(mid)
        .setAnalyticsEnabled(analytics)
        .setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
        .build()

above is the config method which gets triggered on one of the onboarding screens.
I have tried to check the logs and can see this from the sdk state:
{
ConfigETAnalyticsEnabled = 1;
ConfigPIAnalyticsEnabled = 0;
PiIdentifier = "Not Set";
RuntimeETAnalyticsEnabled = 1;
RuntimePIAnalyticsEnabled = 0;
useLegacyPiIdentifier = 0;}

This means that the we are setting the etanalytics value.
But i also see this in the log :
log: `isToggleEnabled: Feature toggle enabled (null) for feature : etanalytics` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFeatureToggle.m` line: `line: 171`

The Push open count were recording some time ago, but its not now.
